# jquery string a lista

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, json, string

Estoy recibiendo un string en una función javascript que quiero convertir en una lista.
lo que tengo es como esto:

```
$.post(url,function(data){
   alert($.type(data));  //string
   alert(data);         // [{'id':'1','name':'user_1'},{'id':'2','name':'user_2'}]
});
```

$.parseJSON() no funciona, porque tiene los corchetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no es un JSON válido, JSON sólo puede usar comillas dobles para definir tanto propiedades como valores de tipo texto. Quien sea que está creando ese JSON, lo está haciendo mal:

```js
let string = `[{'id':'1','name':'user_1'},{'id':'2','name':'user_2'}]`;

try {
  JSON.parse(string);
} catch (error) {
  console.log("Error con el texto original:", error.message);
}
let json = string.replace(/'/g, "\"");
console.log("Texto:", json);
console.log("Objeto obtenido:", JSON.parse(json));
```

La solución es cambiar en el lado del servidor lo que se te está devolviendo

Comment: Si fuese facil que cambien algo en lado del servidor....   Muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo que están devolviendo es erróneo, si una aplicación de mi misma empresa devolviera ese valor tendría ya un ticket abierto como "critical error" :P